# How to download a complete htm webpage with all subpages

Tags: wget, html

I would like to download a complete offline copy of this website with all subpages:

[www.support.robotis.com/en/techsupport_eng.htm](http://www.support.robotis.com/en/techsupport_eng.htm)

I have tried using:

```
wget -m -p -k support.robotis.com/en/techsupport_eng.htm
```

- `-p` should add page-requisites
- `-k` should convert-links
- `-m` should mirror + recurse

I have also tried adding `--html-extension`, but no matter the arguments, it only seems to download the top page I'm linking to and not the subpages + content (~140-150 subpages)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Take a look at the source code: this website does not rely on HTML for its redirections, but uses a lot of javascript to generate the content. I fear `wget` would not be sufficient for this.

Comment: If there is any server-side scripting, programming, database etc you won't get everything. Indeed, you may just get some skeleton pages.